# Как перевести "Approver"?

Tags: перевод

У пользователя в англоязычной системе есть роль "Approver". Он подтверждает заказы обычных пользователей. Как перевести Approver кратко на русский одним словом. Ну, или не слишком пространно, не "пользователь, утверждающий заказы". Так, чтобы помещалось нормально на кнопке.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А просто `Утверждающий` не подойдет?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы понятнее было. Хотя понимаю, что одним словом, скорее всего, никак. Это в выпадающем меню, где есть администратор, обычный пользователь, approver, viewer (тут тоже вопрос, не "смотрящий" же переводить :) Viewer - это тот, у которого read-only доступ ко всем заказам в системе)

Comment: может *утвердитель*?

Comment: Может быть "приёмщик"?

Comment: Заявки наверно, а не заказы? Заказ - это что-то что человек хочет получить себе на дом или на место где он находится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ЖЖ пользователь, который одобряет или не одобряет пост в сообщество, называется модератор. Можно назвать апрувера `модератор` или `модератор заказов`.

Viewer можно перевести как смотритель (если у него не только доступ, но и власть) или наблюдатель.